# TSFRESH - features extracted by a symmetric sliding window

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, feature-extraction, tsfresh

As raw data we have measurements `m_{i,j}`, measured every 30 seconds (`i=0, 30, 60, 90,...720,..`) for every subject `j` in the dataset.

I wish use **TSFRESH** (package) to extract time-series features, such that for a point of interest at time `i`, features are calculated based on **symmetric rolling window.**

We wish to calculate the feature vector of time point `i,j` based on measurements of 3 hours of context before `i` and 3 hours after `i`. 
Thus, the 721-dim feature vector represents a point of interest surrounded by 6 hours “context”, i.e. 360  measurements before and 360 measurements after the point of interest.
For every point of interest, features should be extracted based on 721 measurements of `m_{i,j}`.

I've tried using *`rolling_direction`* param in *`roll_time_series()`*, but the only options are **either roll backwards or forwards in “time”** - I'm looking for a way **to include both "past" and "future" data** in features calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "workaround" solution:

Use the "`roll_time_series`" function twice; one for "**backward**" rolling (setting `rolling_direction=1`) and the second for "**forward**" (`rolling_direction=-1`), and then combine them into one.

This will provide, for each time point in the original dataset `m_{i,j}`$, a time series rolling object with 360 values "from the past" and 360 values "from the future"  (i.e., the time point is at the center of the window and `max_timeshift=360`)

Note to the use of `pandas` functions below: `concat(), sort_values(), drop_duplicates()` - which are **mandatory** for this solution to work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tsfresh.utilities.dataframe_functions import roll_time_series
from tsfresh.feature_extraction import EfficientFCParameters, MinimalFCParameters

rolled_backward = roll_time_series(activity_data,
                                           column_id=id_column,
                                           column_sort=sort_column,
                                           column_kind=None,
                                           rolling_direction=1,
                                           max_timeshift=360)

rolled_farward = roll_time_series(activity_data,
                                           column_id=id_column,
                                           column_sort=sort_column,
                                           column_kind=None,
                                           rolling_direction=-1,
                                           max_timeshift=360)

        # merge into one dataframe, with rolled_farward and rolled_backward window for every time point (sample)
        df = pd.concat([rolled_backward, rolled_farward])

        # important! - sort and drop duplicates
        df.sort_values(by=[id_column, sort_column], inplace=True)
        df.drop_duplicates(subset=[id_column, sort_column, 'activity'], inplace=True, keep='first')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your idea correctly, it is even possible to do this with only one-sided rolling. Let's try with one example:

You want to predict for the time 8:00 - and you need for this the data from 5:00 until 11:00.
 If you roll through the data with a size of 6h and positive rolling direction, you will end up with a dataset, which also includes exactly this part of the data (5:00 to 11:00). Normally, it would be used to train for the value at 11:00 (or 12:00) - but nothing prevents you to use it for predicting the value at 8:00.
Basically, it is just a matter of re-indexing.

(Same is actually true for negative rolling direction)